# Having trouble saving multiple items to Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a noteapp, two pages:

1. MainPage.xaml — the creation of notes;
2. NoteList.xaml — a list of notes.

Notes are saved by means of IsolatedStorage, and appear in NoteList.xaml (listbox), but notes with the same name is not stored, how to fix it?
I need to be able to add notes with the same name (but with different content).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean notes with the same name is not stored? Also could you post some relevant code (save and retrieve perhaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the note name as the file name?  If so... don't do that.  Save each file with a unique name.  There are myriad ways of doing this.  You could use a GUID or a timestamp, or you could append a timestamp to the end of the file name.  If you were so inclined you could store all of the notes in a single formatted file-- perhaps XML.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to uniquely identify each note without using:

a. The note's name

b. The note's contents

While using a timestamp might make sense for your application right now (since a user probably cannot create two disparate notes simultaneously), using a timestamp to identify each note could lead to problems down the line if you wanted to implement say... a server side component to your application. What happens if in version 23 of your application (which obviously sells millions in the first months), you decide to allow users to collaborate on notes, and a Note is shared between two instances of your app where they happened to be created at the EXACT same time? You'd have problems.

A reasonable solution to finding a unique identifier for each Note in your application is through the use of the [`Guid.NewGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) method. You should do this when the user decides to "save" the note (or if your app saves the note the moment it's created, or at some set interval to allow for instant "drafts".

Now that we've sufficiently determined a method of uniquely identifying each Note that your application will allow a user to create, we need to think about how that data should be stored.

A great way to do this is through the use of [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or better yet using the third party library [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). But for the sake of simplicity, I recommend doing something a bit easier.

A simpler method (using good ole' plain text) would be the following:

1: `{Note.Name}`
2: `{Guid.ToString()}`
3: `{Note.Contents}`
4: `{Some delimiter}`

When you are reading the file from IsolatedStorage, you would read through the file line by line, considering each "chunk" of lines between the start of the file and each `{Some delimiter}` and the end of the file to be the data for one "Note".

Keep in mind there are some restrictions with this format. Mainly, you have to keep the user from having the last part of their note's contents be equal to the `{Some delimiter}` (which you are free to arbitrarily define btw). To this end, it may be helpful to use a string of characters the user is not likely to enter, such as "##&&ENDOFNOTE&&##" Regardless of how unlikely it is the user will type that in, you need to check to make sure before you save to IsolatedStorage that the end of the Note does not contain this string, because it will break your file format.

If you want a *simple* solution that works, use the above method. If you want a *good* solution that's scalable, use JSON or XML and figure out a file format that makes sense to you. I highly encourage you to look into JSON, it's value reaches so much further than this isolated scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a need to write notes to IsolatedStorage. What I did was to them them to a file.`IsolatedStorageFile` I write  date on which the note was written and then note. From the list box i store them to two arrays. Then before exiting the app, write them to a file.

```
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile storagefile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (storagefile.FileExists("NotesFile"))
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("NotesFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                            for (int i = 0; i < m_noteCount; i++)
                            {
                                //writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToShortDateString());
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                writer.Write(" ");
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteString[i]);
                                writer.WriteLine("~`");
                            }
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
```